# Basic .htaccess %{REQUEST_URI} not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A WordPress site is being hammered by bots from a number of IP addresses.  The URL is https://example.com/product/something/#comment-1804 but there is no such comment.  I am not even sure why someone is doing this apart from a DOS attempt, but it is a pretty low level site that doesn't have many visitors.

I am trying to force anyone coming to that URL to a 403 page with this to reduce resource and bandwidth usage.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} comment-1804
RewriteRule ^ - [F] [END]
</IfModule>
```

...and the WordPress rules.

But simple as it is, it isn't working.  If I create an error e.g. `%{REQUEST_URI}comment-1804` it breaks the site i.e. the rewrite condition is being read.

What is the problem?

Comment: _"What is the problem?"_ - that the fragment portion of the URL does not get sent to the server in the first place - so you can't do any matching on it there either.

Comment: @CBroe yes, so I discovered, the # fragment is handled by the browser.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this will never work.  The fragment of the URL following a `#` isn't processed in .htaccess

Perhaps this is a trick being used by bots to avoid being blocked in .htaccess.